# What's the RegularExpression that validate more than one thing?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, validation

I am trying to create a custom RegularExpressionValidator to validate the current expression

```
number(0-99).number(100-1000)\number(0-99).number(100-1000)
```

or

```
number(0-99).number(100-1000),number(0-99).number(100-1000)
```

I am trying to create this expression but it didn't work

```
^\-?\d+\.?\d+\(/|,)\-?\d+\.?\d+$
```

What's the correct expression?

Regards,

Comment: I'm not understanding the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you need to match a `\` or a `,` in a regular expression, then this should work:

```
[\\,]
```

The `\` character needs to be escaped (with another `\`).

Putting this into your example above gives (I think)

```
^\-?\d+\.?\d+[\\,]\-?\d+\.?\d+$
```